# Spring Feign Client JSON parse error: Illegal character

Tags: spring, http, kotlin, gzip, feign

I am sending a GET request to an API. This API requires some sort of compression, gzip in my case. Here is the implementation:

**Client**

```
@FeignClient("client",
        url = "someUrl",
        configuration = [ClientConfig::class])
@RequestMapping(consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
interface Client {
    
    @GetMapping("/data")
    fun data(): CustomResponse
}
```

**ClientConfig**

```
class ClientConfig {

    @Bean
    fun gzipFeignRequestInterceptor(): RequestInterceptor {
        return GzipFeignRequestInterceptor()
    }

    class GzipFeignRequestInterceptor : RequestInterceptor {
        override fun apply(template: RequestTemplate) {
            template.header("Accept-Encoding",  "gzip")
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to call the `data()` method I get the following error:

```
feign.codec.DecodeException: Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
```

I understand the error message but I don't know how to fix it. Is it possible to filter the response before it is further processed?

The request itself shouldn't be a problem, when I try to make the same request in the browser it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding the following properties in my `application.yml`

```
feign.compression.response.enabled=true
feign.compression.response.useGzipDecoder=true
```